# Install Bitnami on RHEL

Tags: installation, mediawiki, bitnami

I am trying to install MediaWiki using the Bitnami stack on a RHEL server via command line.  The installer is asking me for:

```
"Please choose a folder that contains an installation of Bitnami."
```

I have tried finding how I install Bitnami itself onto my server, but just keep getting results on how to install stacks.

How do I install Bitnami so I can install a stack?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Windows/bitnami

Comment: @Nemo No I was trying to get it installed on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).  In the end, I abandoned using Bitnami.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

Bitnami Native Installers come in two formats: stand-alone Stacks and Modules. If you only want to install one BitNami-packaged application, then just download and install the Stack. It will contain everything you need to run the application.

If you want to run more than one application, you may want to download a base AMPStack for your platform or RubyStack, which will enable you to install several application Modules on top of it, for example Wordpress module, Redmine module and Mediawiki module. That way, all of the BitNami-packaged applications you want to run will share a single instance of Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc which will save space and improve performance.

You can also install these modules on top of a Virtual Appliance or AMI with LAMP Stack or RubyStack installed. These modules could be also installed from the command line.

In your case, you should install modules.

This warning is due to the installer can not see the properties.ini file that we include in all our stacks. A module need a previous stack installation were it will be placed.

I hope it helps